# Как найти элемент "массива 1" в частях элементов "массива 2" на javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, массивы

У меня есть *"массив 1"*, в нем находятся такие элементы:

```
0:"дерево"
1:"древесина"
2:"лес"
```

есть *"массив 2"*, в нем есть такие элементы:

```
0:"wood frog — древесная лягушка"
1:"compressed wood — прессованная древесина"
2:"wood takes a finish — дерево и древесина поддаётся отделке"
```

Мне необходимо, чтобы был найден ***третий*** элемент массива 2, так как в нем присутствует ***первый*** элемент массива 1. И так далее.

Как это делается? 
Единственное о чем я пока думаю, это с помощью оператора for. Так или иначе?

Comment: Добавьте код или вопрос закроют.

Comment: Можно использовать `Array.prototype.filter()`

Comment: А второй элемент *массива 2* должен быть найден? В нем есть второй элемент *массива 1*. Поясните задачу

Comment: Блин, вот я... Да, должен быть найдет второй элемент (2:"wood takes a finish — дерево и древесина поддаётся отделке"). Задача: искать все элементы в массиве 2, где есть слово из первого (0:"дерево") элемента массива 1. И так до бесконечности, если там больше элементов.

Comment: за что минусы ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
var i; // просто номера
var c_end = arr2.length // количество элементов в массиве 2
var d_end = arr1.length // количество элементов в массиве 1
var c = arr2; // словосочетания (3)
var d = arr1; // переводы (5)
var c_i = 0; // начало для массива с 
var d_i = 0; // начало для массива d
var e; // тут переводы 

for ( c[c_i] ; c_i < c_end ; c_i++) {
    for ( d[d_i] ; d_i < d_end ; d_i++ ) {
        c.forEach( (e, i) => (e.indexOf(d[d_i]) != -1) && 
    console.log("слово >>", d[d_i], "<< присутствует в словосочетание: ", e))

    }
};
```

вот я сделал, но мне помогли

Comment: в javascript-е стандарт написания кода не underscore а camel case.Придерживайтесь этого стандарта .

Comment: ок, позтораюсь, хорошо